# Как модифицировать почти работающий скрипт, реализующий альтернативный скроллбар на странице через drag-n-drop? javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, drag-n-drop

**Вкратце:** хочу реализовать скроллбар альтернативный системному.

**Если запустить код в FF**, то наглядно видно, что всё вроде как работает, но скроллинг путем перетаскивания слайдера (функция **DragElement**) очень медленный, если попытку реализации скроллинга на это событие не вешать, то **drag-n-drop** слайдера работает почти без нареканий.

**На хромиуме** скроллинг слайдером работает так, как если бы я положил его во вложенную функцию (**closeDragElement**), т.е. **drag-n-drop** работает как и положено, но скролл срабатывает только после того как отработает **onmouseup**, а не в реальном времени.

Остальной код оставлю для наглядности и целостности картины.

**Описание функций:**

**1.altScroll(e)** - реализация скролла через колесо мыши (спешл фор FF, который не дружит со скрытыми скроллбарами)

**2.CorrectPos()** - реализация подобия "резиновости" скроллбара

**3.DragElement(elmnt) - собственно сабж (так еще говорят?)**

**4.const btnUp** - кнопка для прокрутки страницы в начало (функцию подсмотрел, поэтому хз зачем в постоянную её записали, буду благодарен если кто-нибудь объяснит)

**5.Ymonitor()** - монитор с координатами для наглядности

**6.SlideByScroll()** - ну если скроллинг через слайдер у меня реализовать не получилось, то слайдинг через скроллер вполне :))

**Из своих мыслей:** похоже на то, что **drag-n-drop** и скроллинг не могут поделить срабатывания и срабатывают почти единовременно, поэтому слайдер себя так и ведёт странно, но каким образом поставить задержку между ними я ума не приложу, знаю что через **setTimeout** это делается, но куда и как впихнуть его не понимаю.

**UPD:** В общем пока решения я так и не нашел, но пришел к мысли, что было бы неплохо связать положение слайдера с положением прокрутки на все случаи жизни и в одну сторону, т.е. скроллить **только через слайдер**, а для изменения положения слайдера вешать на него и drag-n-drop и колесо мыши. Сейчас скроллинг колесом мыши это - зависимость положения слайдера от величины прокрутки по оси Y, а по-хорошему хочется чтобы величина прокрутки зависела **только от положения слайдера**. **Пока работаю в этом направлении, прошу ответы давать связанные именно с кодом из вопроса. Спасибо!**

**Помогите разобраться:** в правильном ли вообще направлении я работаю? Кажется, что от реализации меня отделяет одна строчка кода. Писать за меня не прошу, знаю, что здесь такое не приветствуется, прошу дать напутствие или наводящих вопросов.

**Заранее спасибо за ответы!**

**P.S. в снипете на сайте код работает не так, как в браузере((**

```js
window.addEventListener("wheel", altScroll);
         
    function altScroll(e) {
      
     let delta = e.deltaY
     if (delta > 0) {
      window.scrollTo({
            top: window.scrollY+75,
            left: 0,
            behavior: 'auto'
          }); 
     } else { window.scrollTo({
            top: window.scrollY-75,
            left: 0,
            behavior: 'auto'
          });

     }     
    } 
window.addEventListener("load", CorrectPos());

    function CorrectPos() {

        let windowHeight = window.innerHeight;

        let SliderendsHeight = window.getComputedStyle(scrollbarTop, null).getPropertyValue("height");
        SliderendsHeight = parseFloat(SliderendsHeight);
        let minYvalue = ((windowHeight-(windowHeight*0.95))+SliderendsHeight*2)/2;
        minYvalue = minYvalue.toFixed(3);

        document.getElementById("scrollbarSlider").style.top = minYvalue+"px";

        let endsHeight = window.getComputedStyle(altScrollbarTop, null).getPropertyValue("height");
        endsHeight = parseFloat(endsHeight);
        endsHeight = endsHeight*2
        let allScrollHeight = windowHeight*0.95;
        let allScrollCenterHeight = allScrollHeight-endsHeight;
        let allScrollTop = (windowHeight - allScrollHeight)/2;

        document.getElementById("altScrollbarCenter").style.height = allScrollCenterHeight + "px";

        document.getElementById("altScrollbar").style.height = allScrollHeight + "px";

        document.getElementById("altScrollbar").style.top = allScrollTop + "px"; 


       addEventListener("scroll",() =>{

        let windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
        let endsHeight = window.getComputedStyle(altScrollbarTop, null).getPropertyValue("height");
        endsHeight = parseFloat(endsHeight);
        endsHeight = endsHeight*2
        let allScrollHeight = windowHeight*0.95;
        let allScrollCenterHeight = allScrollHeight-endsHeight;
        let allScrollTop = (windowHeight - allScrollHeight)/2;

        document.getElementById("altScrollbarCenter").style.height = allScrollCenterHeight + "px";

        document.getElementById("altScrollbar").style.height = allScrollHeight + "px";

        document.getElementById("altScrollbar").style.top = allScrollTop + "px";
          
        });        
        
      }
DragElement(document.getElementById("scrollbarSlider"));

      function DragElement(elmnt) {


      var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;

      elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;

      function dragMouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  }

  function elementDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    // calculate the new cursor position:
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;

    let SliderRight = window.getComputedStyle(scrollbarSlider, null).getPropertyValue("right"); 
    SliderRight = parseFloat(SliderRight);

    let SliderHeight = window.getComputedStyle(scrollbarSlider, null).getPropertyValue("height"); 
    SliderHeight = parseFloat(SliderHeight);

    let fullField = Math.max( document.body.scrollHeight, document.body.offsetHeight, document.body.clientHeight, document.body.scrollHeight);

    let windowHeight = window.innerHeight;

    let pageScrollRange = fullField - windowHeight;

    let SliderendsHeight = window.getComputedStyle(scrollbarTop, null).getPropertyValue("height");
    SliderendsHeight = parseFloat(SliderendsHeight);
    SliderendsHeight - SliderendsHeight*2;
    let minYvalue = ((windowHeight-(windowHeight*0.95))+SliderendsHeight)/2;

    let scrollbarRange = windowHeight-minYvalue-SliderHeight;
    
    scrollbarRange = parseInt(scrollbarRange);
    minYvalue = minYvalue.toFixed(3);

    let getSliderPos = parseFloat(elmnt.style.top);

    if (getSliderPos<minYvalue) { 
     elmnt.style.top = minYvalue + "px"; 
     elmnt.style.right = SliderRight + "px";
      } else {
        if (getSliderPos>scrollbarRange) {
        elmnt.style.top = scrollbarRange + "px"; 
        elmnt.style.right = SliderRight + "px";
    }     else{
            elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px"; 
            elmnt.style.right = SliderRight + "px";
    }
   } 

  let getCurrentRange = getSliderPos*pageScrollRange/scrollbarRange;
  
  window.scrollTo({
            top: getCurrentRange,
            left: 0,
            behavior: 'auto'
          });                   
  }

  function closeDragElement() {


    /* stop moving when mouse button is released:*/
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
  elmnt.ondragstart = function() {
  return false;
};
}

const btnUp = {
      el: document.querySelector('.arrowbg'),
      show() {
        
        this.el.classList.remove('hidebtn');
      },
      hide() {
        
        this.el.classList.add('hidebtn');
      },
      addEventListener() {
        
        window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
          
          let scrollY = window.scrollY || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
          
          scrollY > 400 ? this.show() : this.hide();
        });
        document.querySelector('.arrowbg').onclick = () => {
          
          window.scrollTo({
            top: 0,
            left: 0,
            behavior: 'smooth'
          });
        }
      }
    }
    btnUp.addEventListener();
function Ymonitor(){

  let fF = Math.max( document.body.scrollHeight, document.body.offsetHeight, document.body.clientHeight, document.body.scrollHeight);


    document.getElementById('Ymntr').value = window.pageYOffset+";"+"\n"+fF+";"+"\n"+document.body.scrollWidth+";"+"\n"+"\n"+window.innerWidth+";"+"\n"+window.innerHeight+";";


    addEventListener('scroll', () =>{
    document.getElementById('Ymntr').value = window.pageYOffset+";"+"\n"+fF+";"+"\n"+document.body.scrollWidth+";"+"\n"+"\n"+window.innerWidth+";"+"\n"+window.innerHeight+";";
  });
 }

 window.addEventListener("load", Ymonitor());
window.addEventListener("load", SlideByScroll());


  function SlideByScroll() {
  
   addEventListener('scroll', () =>{

   let currentRange = window.pageYOffset;

   let fullField = Math.max( document.body.scrollHeight, document.body.offsetHeight, document.body.clientHeight, document.body.scrollHeight);

   let windowHeight = window.innerHeight;

   let pageScrollRange = fullField - windowHeight;

   let SliderendsHeight = window.getComputedStyle(scrollbarTop, null).getPropertyValue("height");
   SliderendsHeight = parseFloat(SliderendsHeight);
   let minYvalue = ((windowHeight-(windowHeight*0.95))+SliderendsHeight*2)/2;
   minYvalue = minYvalue.toFixed(3);

   let SliderHeight = window.getComputedStyle(scrollbarSlider, null).getPropertyValue("height");
   SliderHeight = parseFloat(SliderHeight);

   let scrollbarRange = windowHeight-minYvalue-SliderHeight;
   
   scrollbarRange = parseInt(scrollbarRange);

   let SliderPos = currentRange*scrollbarRange/pageScrollRange;

     if (SliderPos<minYvalue) {    
       SliderPos = minYvalue;
       } else {
           if (SliderPos>scrollbarRange) {
             SliderPos = scrollbarRange;
             } 
            } 

  document.getElementById("scrollbarSlider").style.top = SliderPos+"px";       

  
 });
}
```

```css
body {
 border-top: 1px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
 overflow: hidden;
 min-width: ;
 min-height: 3000px;
 margin: 0px;
 background-color: rgba(30, 30, 30, 0.5);
 }
      

#altScrollbar {
  border: ;
  z-index: 1;
  position: fixed ;
  width: 15px; height:;
  right: 10px; top:;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0);
  }

  #altScrollbarTop {
  z-index: 1;
  width: 15px; height: 15px;
  right: 10px; top:;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  border-top-left-radius: 50%;
  border-top-right-radius: 50%;
}

  #altScrollbarCenter {
  border: ;  
  z-index: 1;
  width: 15px; height: ;
  right: 10px; top:;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}

#altScrollbarBottom {
  z-index: 1;
  width: 15px; height: 15px;
  right: 10px; top:;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
}

#scrollbarSlider {
  z-index: 3;
  -moz-user-select:none;
  user-select: none;
  position: fixed;
  width: 7px; height: 59px;
  right: 14px;  
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
  cursor: pointer; 
}


 #scrollbarTop {
 width: 7px; height: 7px;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
 border-top-left-radius: 50%;
 border-top-right-radius: 50%;
}

#scrollbarCenter {
  
  -moz-user-select:none;
  user-select: none;
  width: 7px; height: 45px;  
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  cursor: pointer;
}

 #scrollbarBottom {
  width: 7px; height: 7px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
}
.arrowbg {

 fill-opacity: 0.4;
 transition: all 0.3s; 
 width: 80px; height: 80px;
 position: fixed;
 right: 35px;
 bottom: 35px; 
 cursor: pointer;

}

.arrowbg::before {
      content: "";
      width: 40px;
      height: 40px;
      background: transparent no-repeat center center;
      background-size: 100% 100%;
  }


.hidebtn{
  opacity: 0;
} 

.arrowbg:hover {
 fill-opacity: 0.55;
 width: 80px; height: 80px;
 position: fixed;
 right: 35px;
 bottom: 50px;
 

}


.Ymonitor {
    width: 100px; height: 100px;
    position: fixed;
    left: 30px;
    bottom: 35px;
}

.Ymonitor::before {
  content: "";
      width: 40px;
      height: 40px;
      background: transparent no-repeat center center;
      background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.Ymonitorindicator {
  outline: 1px solid #000;
  pointer-events: none;
  resize: none;
  width: 99px; height: 99px;
}
.Ymonitorindicator:focus {

    outline: none; 
   }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<html>

  <head>

    <title>Учебное пространство</title>

  </head>

  <body>

    
<center><p><h1>Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку!Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку!Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку!Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку!Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку!Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку!Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку!Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку!Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку!Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку!</h1></p></center> 

<div id="altScrollbar">
  <div id="altScrollbarTop"></div>
    <div  id="altScrollbarCenter">
    
       <div id="scrollbarSlider">
        <div id="scrollbarTop"></div>
          <div id="scrollbarCenter"></div>
        <div id="scrollbarBottom"></div>
      </div>

    </div>
  <div id="altScrollbarBottom"></div>
</div>
<div class="arrowbg hidebtn" > 

      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xml:space="preserve" width="80px" height="80px" version="1.1" style="shape-rendering:geometricPrecision; text-rendering:geometricPrecision; image-rendering:optimizeQuality; fill-rule:evenodd; clip-rule:evenodd"
viewBox="0 0 300 300"
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
 <defs>
  <style type="text/css">
   <![CDATA[
    .str0 {stroke:#2B2A29;stroke-width:0.9;stroke-miterlimit:22.9256}
    .fil1 {fill:none}
    .fil0 {fill:#FEFEFE}
   ]]>
  </style>
 </defs>
 <g id="arrowUp">
   <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="150"  />
  
  <path class="fil0" d="M150 289.59c-77.1,0 -139.59,-62.49 -139.59,-139.59 0,-77.1 62.49,-139.59 139.59,-139.59 77.1,0 139.59,62.49 139.59,139.59 0,77.1 -62.49,139.59 -139.59,139.59zm148.68 -139.59c0,-82.11 -66.57,-148.68 -148.68,-148.68 -82.11,0 -148.68,66.57 -148.68,148.68 0,82.11 66.57,148.68 148.68,148.68 82.11,0 148.68,-66.57 148.68,-148.68z"/>
  <path class="fil0" d="M178.48 136.12c-3,25 -1,64 45,98 -87,1 -110,-38 -114,-98l-30 0c-6,0 -8,-2 0,-10l54 -55c7,-7 14,-7 20,0l55 55c8,8 6,10 0,10l-30 0z"/>
  <path class="fil1 str0" d="M-503.9 -364.45c0,-82.11 -66.57,-148.68 -148.68,-148.68 -82.11,0 -148.68,66.57 -148.68,148.68 0,82.12 66.57,148.68 148.68,148.68 82.11,0 148.68,-66.56 148.68,-148.68z"/>
  <path class="fil1 str0" d="M-554.48 -17.31c0,-77.09 -62.49,-139.59 -139.59,-139.59 -77.09,0 -139.59,62.5 -139.59,139.59 0,77.1 62.5,139.6 139.59,139.6 77.1,0 139.59,-62.5 139.59,-139.6z"/>
 </g>
</svg> 

  </div>
<div class="Ymonitor">
   
  <textarea class="Ymonitorindicator" id="Ymntr"></textarea>

 </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Написать свой велосипед с таким опытом дело конечно похвальное, но мое мнение, — направление не правильное, по крайней мере я не вижу смысла в альтернативном скроллбаре когда всю ту же функциональность и вид (+- для разных браузеров) можно реализовать с помощью нативного скроллбара (полно статей с примерами  [стилизуем скроллбар css примеры](https://only-to-top.ru/blog/coding/2020-01-31-stilizaciya-skrolla-css.html)) разумеется drag-n-drop придется дописать самому, но это будет сделать гораздо легче.

Comment: Товарищ, всё ж работает в коде...почти, подскажи как исправить или чего добавить, если знаешь, или можешь наводящих вопросов мне дать, если педагогический подход тебе не чужд, я готов сидеть и учиться, но для этого мне нужно понимать в какую сторону. Я знаю, что можно просто плагин подключить и просто всё настроить, но задача именно в том, чтобы реализовать всё именно "ванильными" средствами. Из CSS для FF настраивается форма скроллбара, а выбрать можно только две или просто скрыть, и два цвета, никаких всплываний и изменений форм, никакого праздника в общем.

Comment: @DaniilLoban спасибо за ссылку, инфа полезная, плагин описан хороший (скроллбары там, кстати очень похожи на мою недоразработку визуально), обязательно воспользуюсь им, НО только в случае полного отчаяния и разочарования в своих способностях, а про СSS уже написал, что в FF сильно не разгуляешься с ним, а сверстать так, чтобы хотя бы в двух браузерных движках работало и при этом красиво, хочется очень.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Довёл скрипт до ума, я предполагал, что от решения меня отделяет одна строчка кода, но я не подозревал, что даже меньше.

В общем вот я сделяль, корявенько, но работает, я собой доволен) чтобы посмотреть из снипета разворачивайте на полный экран - в миниатюре не работает.

**В двух словах о доработке:** прямо в последней строчке кода функции от значения величины на сколько должна быть прокручена страница отнял разницу изменения координат и умножил на 2.

Буду теперь пробовать реализовать свою задумку, чтобы всё от положения слайдера считалось.

```js
window.addEventListener("wheel", altScroll);
         
    function altScroll(e) {
      
     let delta = e.deltaY
     if (delta > 0) {
      window.scrollTo({
            top: window.scrollY+75,
            left: 0,
            behavior: 'auto'
          }); 
     } else { window.scrollTo({
            top: window.scrollY-75,
            left: 0,
            behavior: 'auto'
          });

     }     
    } 
window.addEventListener("load", CorrectPos());

    function CorrectPos() {

        let windowHeight = window.innerHeight;

        let SliderendsHeight = window.getComputedStyle(scrollbarTop, null).getPropertyValue("height");
        SliderendsHeight = parseFloat(SliderendsHeight);
        let minYvalue = ((windowHeight-(windowHeight*0.95))+SliderendsHeight*2)/2;
        minYvalue = minYvalue.toFixed(3);

        document.getElementById("scrollbarSlider").style.top = minYvalue+"px";

        let endsHeight = window.getComputedStyle(altScrollbarTop, null).getPropertyValue("height");
        endsHeight = parseFloat(endsHeight);
        endsHeight = endsHeight*2
        let allScrollHeight = windowHeight*0.95;
        let allScrollCenterHeight = allScrollHeight-endsHeight;
        let allScrollTop = (windowHeight - allScrollHeight)/2;

        document.getElementById("altScrollbarCenter").style.height = allScrollCenterHeight + "px";

        document.getElementById("altScrollbar").style.height = allScrollHeight + "px";

        document.getElementById("altScrollbar").style.top = allScrollTop + "px"; 


       addEventListener("scroll",() =>{

        let windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
        let endsHeight = window.getComputedStyle(altScrollbarTop, null).getPropertyValue("height");
        endsHeight = parseFloat(endsHeight);
        endsHeight = endsHeight*2
        let allScrollHeight = windowHeight*0.95;
        let allScrollCenterHeight = allScrollHeight-endsHeight;
        let allScrollTop = (windowHeight - allScrollHeight)/2;

        document.getElementById("altScrollbarCenter").style.height = allScrollCenterHeight + "px";

        document.getElementById("altScrollbar").style.height = allScrollHeight + "px";

        document.getElementById("altScrollbar").style.top = allScrollTop + "px";
          
        });        
        
      }
DragElement(document.getElementById("scrollbarSlider"));

      function DragElement(elmnt) {


      var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;

      elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;

      function dragMouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  }

  function elementDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    // calculate the new cursor position:
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;

    let SliderRight = window.getComputedStyle(scrollbarSlider, null).getPropertyValue("right"); 
    SliderRight = parseFloat(SliderRight);

    let SliderHeight = window.getComputedStyle(scrollbarSlider, null).getPropertyValue("height"); 
    SliderHeight = parseFloat(SliderHeight);

    let fullField = Math.max( document.body.scrollHeight, document.body.offsetHeight, document.body.clientHeight, document.body.scrollHeight);

    let windowHeight = window.innerHeight;

    let pageScrollRange = fullField - windowHeight;

    let SliderendsHeight = window.getComputedStyle(scrollbarTop, null).getPropertyValue("height");
    SliderendsHeight = parseFloat(SliderendsHeight);
    SliderendsHeight - SliderendsHeight*2;
    let minYvalue = ((windowHeight-(windowHeight*0.95))+SliderendsHeight)/2;

    let scrollbarRange = windowHeight-minYvalue-SliderHeight;
    
    scrollbarRange = parseInt(scrollbarRange);
    minYvalue = minYvalue.toFixed(3);

    let getSliderPos = parseFloat(elmnt.style.top);

    if (getSliderPos<minYvalue) { 
     elmnt.style.top = minYvalue + "px"; 
     elmnt.style.right = SliderRight + "px";
      } else {
        if (getSliderPos>scrollbarRange) {
        elmnt.style.top = scrollbarRange + "px"; 
        elmnt.style.right = SliderRight + "px";
    }     else{
            elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px"; 
            elmnt.style.right = SliderRight + "px";
    }
   } 

  let getCurrentRange = getSliderPos*pageScrollRange/scrollbarRange;
  
  window.scrollTo({
            top: getCurrentRange-pos2*2,
            left: 0,
            behavior: 'auto'
          });                   
  }

  function closeDragElement() {


    /* stop moving when mouse button is released:*/
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
  elmnt.ondragstart = function() {
  return false;
};
}

const btnUp = {
      el: document.querySelector('.arrowbg'),
      show() {
        
        this.el.classList.remove('hidebtn');
      },
      hide() {
        
        this.el.classList.add('hidebtn');
      },
      addEventListener() {
        
        window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
          
          let scrollY = window.scrollY || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
          
          scrollY > 400 ? this.show() : this.hide();
        });
        document.querySelector('.arrowbg').onclick = () => {
          
          window.scrollTo({
            top: 0,
            left: 0,
            behavior: 'smooth'
          });
        }
      }
    }
    btnUp.addEventListener();
function Ymonitor(){

  let fF = Math.max( document.body.scrollHeight, document.body.offsetHeight, document.body.clientHeight, document.body.scrollHeight);


    document.getElementById('Ymntr').value = window.pageYOffset+";"+"\n"+fF+";"+"\n"+document.body.scrollWidth+";"+"\n"+"\n"+window.innerWidth+";"+"\n"+window.innerHeight+";";


    addEventListener('scroll', () =>{
    document.getElementById('Ymntr').value = window.pageYOffset+";"+"\n"+fF+";"+"\n"+document.body.scrollWidth+";"+"\n"+"\n"+window.innerWidth+";"+"\n"+window.innerHeight+";";
  });
 }

 window.addEventListener("load", Ymonitor());
window.addEventListener("load", SlideByScroll());


  function SlideByScroll() {
  
   addEventListener('scroll', () =>{

   let currentRange = window.pageYOffset;

   let fullField = Math.max( document.body.scrollHeight, document.body.offsetHeight, document.body.clientHeight, document.body.scrollHeight);

   let windowHeight = window.innerHeight;

   let pageScrollRange = fullField - windowHeight;

   let SliderendsHeight = window.getComputedStyle(scrollbarTop, null).getPropertyValue("height");
   SliderendsHeight = parseFloat(SliderendsHeight);
   let minYvalue = ((windowHeight-(windowHeight*0.95))+SliderendsHeight*2)/2;
   minYvalue = minYvalue.toFixed(3);

   let SliderHeight = window.getComputedStyle(scrollbarSlider, null).getPropertyValue("height");
   SliderHeight = parseFloat(SliderHeight);

   let scrollbarRange = windowHeight-minYvalue-SliderHeight;
   
   scrollbarRange = parseInt(scrollbarRange);

   let SliderPos = currentRange*scrollbarRange/pageScrollRange;

     if (SliderPos<minYvalue) {    
       SliderPos = minYvalue;
       } else {
           if (SliderPos>scrollbarRange) {
             SliderPos = scrollbarRange;
             } 
            } 

  document.getElementById("scrollbarSlider").style.top = SliderPos+"px";       

  
 });
}
```

```css
body {
 border-top: 1px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
 overflow: hidden;
 min-width: ;
 min-height: 3000px;
 margin: 0px;
 background-color: rgba(30, 30, 30, 0.5);
 }
      

#altScrollbar {
  border: ;
  z-index: 1;
  position: fixed ;
  width: 15px; height:;
  right: 10px; top:;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0);
  }

  #altScrollbarTop {
  z-index: 1;
  width: 15px; height: 15px;
  right: 10px; top:;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  border-top-left-radius: 50%;
  border-top-right-radius: 50%;
}

  #altScrollbarCenter {
  border: ;  
  z-index: 1;
  width: 15px; height: ;
  right: 10px; top:;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}

#altScrollbarBottom {
  z-index: 1;
  width: 15px; height: 15px;
  right: 10px; top:;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
}

#scrollbarSlider {
  z-index: 3;
  -moz-user-select:none;
  user-select: none;
  position: fixed;
  width: 7px; height: 59px;
  right: 14px;  
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
  cursor: pointer; 
}


 #scrollbarTop {
 width: 7px; height: 7px;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
 border-top-left-radius: 50%;
 border-top-right-radius: 50%;
}

#scrollbarCenter {
  
  -moz-user-select:none;
  user-select: none;
  width: 7px; height: 45px;  
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  cursor: pointer;
}

 #scrollbarBottom {
  width: 7px; height: 7px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
}
.arrowbg {

 fill-opacity: 0.4;
 transition: all 0.3s; 
 width: 80px; height: 80px;
 position: fixed;
 right: 35px;
 bottom: 35px; 
 cursor: pointer;

}

.arrowbg::before {
      content: "";
      width: 40px;
      height: 40px;
      background: transparent no-repeat center center;
      background-size: 100% 100%;
  }


.hidebtn{
  opacity: 0;
} 

.arrowbg:hover {
 fill-opacity: 0.55;
 width: 80px; height: 80px;
 position: fixed;
 right: 35px;
 bottom: 50px;
 

}


.Ymonitor {
    width: 100px; height: 100px;
    position: fixed;
    left: 30px;
    bottom: 35px;
}

.Ymonitor::before {
  content: "";
      width: 40px;
      height: 40px;
      background: transparent no-repeat center center;
      background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.Ymonitorindicator {
  outline: 1px solid #000;
  pointer-events: none;
  resize: none;
  width: 99px; height: 99px;
}
.Ymonitorindicator:focus {

    outline: none; 
   }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<html>

  <head>

    <title>Учебное пространство</title>

  </head>

  <body>

    
<center><p><h1>Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку!Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку!Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку!Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку!Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку!Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку!Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку!Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку!Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку!Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку! Текст, чтобы видеть прокрутку!</h1></p></center> 

<div id="altScrollbar">
  <div id="altScrollbarTop"></div>
    <div  id="altScrollbarCenter">
    
       <div id="scrollbarSlider">
        <div id="scrollbarTop"></div>
          <div id="scrollbarCenter"></div>
        <div id="scrollbarBottom"></div>
      </div>

    </div>
  <div id="altScrollbarBottom"></div>
</div>
<div class="arrowbg hidebtn" > 

      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xml:space="preserve" width="80px" height="80px" version="1.1" style="shape-rendering:geometricPrecision; text-rendering:geometricPrecision; image-rendering:optimizeQuality; fill-rule:evenodd; clip-rule:evenodd"
viewBox="0 0 300 300"
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
 <defs>
  <style type="text/css">
   <![CDATA[
    .str0 {stroke:#2B2A29;stroke-width:0.9;stroke-miterlimit:22.9256}
    .fil1 {fill:none}
    .fil0 {fill:#FEFEFE}
   ]]>
  </style>
 </defs>
 <g id="arrowUp">
   <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="150"  />
  
  <path class="fil0" d="M150 289.59c-77.1,0 -139.59,-62.49 -139.59,-139.59 0,-77.1 62.49,-139.59 139.59,-139.59 77.1,0 139.59,62.49 139.59,139.59 0,77.1 -62.49,139.59 -139.59,139.59zm148.68 -139.59c0,-82.11 -66.57,-148.68 -148.68,-148.68 -82.11,0 -148.68,66.57 -148.68,148.68 0,82.11 66.57,148.68 148.68,148.68 82.11,0 148.68,-66.57 148.68,-148.68z"/>
  <path class="fil0" d="M178.48 136.12c-3,25 -1,64 45,98 -87,1 -110,-38 -114,-98l-30 0c-6,0 -8,-2 0,-10l54 -55c7,-7 14,-7 20,0l55 55c8,8 6,10 0,10l-30 0z"/>
  <path class="fil1 str0" d="M-503.9 -364.45c0,-82.11 -66.57,-148.68 -148.68,-148.68 -82.11,0 -148.68,66.57 -148.68,148.68 0,82.12 66.57,148.68 148.68,148.68 82.11,0 148.68,-66.56 148.68,-148.68z"/>
  <path class="fil1 str0" d="M-554.48 -17.31c0,-77.09 -62.49,-139.59 -139.59,-139.59 -77.09,0 -139.59,62.5 -139.59,139.59 0,77.1 62.5,139.6 139.59,139.6 77.1,0 139.59,-62.5 139.59,-139.6z"/>
 </g>
</svg> 

  </div>
<div class="Ymonitor">
   
  <textarea class="Ymonitorindicator" id="Ymntr"></textarea>

 </div>
</body>

</html>
```